# Is it Bufo bufo?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

I find a couple of frogs. It was cca. 4inches long and 2inches wide. Photo was taken in Prague, Czech republic, middle Europe.[image]. Same zoomed.[image]

Comment: Just want to be sure, guys.

Comment: I suggest this is definatly a toad. Thank you guys anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is almost certainly *Bufo bufo*.
It has the stocky figure and the warty skin, ruling out the true frogs.
It lacks the stripes of *B. calamita* or *Pelobatus fuscus*.
It is brown without the green colors of *Alytes obstetricans*.
A red yellow or red belly is not visible at the photos, but I assume you would have noticed it if it was present (ruling out *Bombina sp.*).
See [here](https://determineren.nederlandsesoorten.nl/linnaeus_ng/app/views/matrixkey/index.php?p=kikkerspadden) for some pictures of European toads (not complete and in Dutch, but pictures and latin names are clear.

Finally: a city like Prague lacks specific habitats of the more rare species.  Common toad is the most likely to be found there.